# copy and paste formulas quickly

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write a simple code that copies the value from one cell and paste its formula into all the cells in one column (There are several cells, around 3000). The code works, but it takes around 30 min to run, so it's not ok for me. I also tried to let the value of the formula without "=" and then use the replace command, but it does not work as well. Anyone could help me with that in order to run the macro in 1 min? This is the part of my code that I try to do that:

```
sub copy_paste

Worksheets("Formatar").Range("H1:L1").Copy
Worksheets("Formatar").Range("H3").PasteSpecial xlValue
Worksheets("Formatar").Range("H3:L3").Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlFormulas

end sub
```

Comment: It may have helped to actually show the formula (or a reasonable facsimile) that you are filling down. Are the results of the formula fairly static or do they change often?

Comment: Also what's in column H when you run this? If it's empty from H4 down, you're actually filling over a million rows.

Comment: In your code, you are copying the value of the cell, not the formula. Copy from H1:L1 to H3, here you paste values, and then copy that (the values), and paste it from H3:L3 to the end of the blank cells, using... xlFormulas!?!?!... Let me put an answer...

Answer (score 5):

Tell me if this help you...

```
Sub copy_paste()
    Worksheets("Formatar").Range("H1:L1").Copy 'Copy from row 1
    Worksheets("Formatar").Range("H3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste the values to row 3
    Worksheets("Formatar").Range("H3:L3").Copy 'here you copy that (the values) 
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'you select eveything from row3 
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'and paste it... but you copy just values from 3! 
End Sub
```

And then you paste it over the first occurrence and you lost data.

Here is my suggest.

```
Sub copy_paste()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim r
    Dim H
    Dim L
    
    Set sht = Sheets("Formatar") 'store the sheet
    
    sht.Activate 'activate it!
    Range("H1:L1").Copy
    Range("H3").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas 'Paste the formula
    Range("H3:L3").Copy 'then copy again
    
    H = Range("H1").Column 'Just to take the number of the columns H and L
    L = Range("L1").Column
    
    r = Range("H3").End(xlDown).Row - 1 'Take the number of the last blank row.
    Range(Cells(3, H), Cells(r, L)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Here you paste values, of if you need the
    'formula use this: xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'never forget this...
End Sub
```

**Edit**

May be this could help...

```
'Application.Calculation = xlManual



Sub copy_paste()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim r
    Dim H
    Dim L
    
    Set sht = Sheets("Formatar") 'store the sheet
    
    sht.Activate 'activate it!
    Range("H1:L1").Copy
    Range("H3").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas 'Paste the formula
    Application.Calculation = xlManual 'Not automatic calculation
    Range("H3:L3").Copy 'then copy again
    
    H = Range("H1").Column 'Just to take the number of the columns H and L
    L = Range("L1").Column
    
    r = Range("H3").End(xlDown).Row - 1 'Take the number of the last blank row.
    Range(Cells(3, H), Cells(r, L)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Here you paste values, of if you need the
    'formula use this: xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'never forget this...
    Calculate 'Calculate the whole sheet
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'return automatic calculation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Elbert, but when I use xlPasteFormulas (what I need), it still take a long time. Do you have any suggestion to make it in less time?

Comment: Well, is hard to say somenthing because, I wuold need to see the whole file, the formulas, sheets sizes, number of sheets, and also the kind of computer, at some times these issues influence the speed of execution.